# Reformat data while reading it in from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that was given to me in a format that cannot be directly converted into a dataframe object without formatting the data first. I need to combine data from x consecutive rows.

My sample data looks like this:

```
ID     Date      Stock       Quantity      Price
aaa    1Dec23    Google        10            1000 
                 Apple
bbb    1Jan23    Google        10            1000
                 Apple                    
ccc    1Feb23    Google        10            1000 
                 Apple                  
ddd    1Mar23    Facebook      10            1000 
                 Google                    
                 Apple
eee    1Apr23    Google        10            1000 
                 Apple
```

My output should look like this:

```
ID     Date      Stock                       Quantity         Price
aaa    1Dec23    [Google,Apple]                 10            1000 
bbb    1Jan23    [Google,Apple]                 10            1000 
ccc    1Feb23    [Google,Apple]                 10            1000                 
ddd    1Mar23    [Facebook,Google,Apple]        10            1000 
eee    1Apr23    [Google,Apple]                 10            1000
```

I have this code which only works for 2 consecutive rows. The case for 3 consecutive rows only works for the first instance, then does not work because i is always being incremented by 2. I need a dynamic solution to determine how many consecutive rows need to be combined but I am struggling with a solution:

```
# loop through dataframe 
for i in range(0, len(df)-1, 2):
        
    # locate two consecutive rows
    row1 = df.iloc[i]
    row2 = df.iloc[i + 1] if i + 1 < len(df) else None
    
    # check if the third consecutive row is empty
    # if it is empty we need to combine this row as well
    if str.strip(df.iloc[i + 2, 0]) == '': 
        row3 = df.iloc[i + 2] if i + 2 < len(df) else None
    else:
        row3 = None

    # create a dictionary 
    combined_row = {}

    # loop through each column
    # if the column needs to be combined, 
    # get the data from the rows and store it in dictionary 
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in ['Stock']:  # Specify the columns to be combined
            if row3 is None:
                combined_row[col] = [row1[col], row2[col] if row2 is not None else None]
                print(combined_row[col])
            else: 
                combined_row[col] = [row1[col], row2[col] if row2 is not None else None, row3[col]]
                print(combined_row[col])
        else:
            combined_row[col] = row1[col]
            print(combined_row[col])

    # append dictionary to dataframe
    formatted_df = formatted_df._append(combined_row, ignore_index=True)
```

I am using python pandas

Comment: Your example is not clear. What are the names of indexes and columns? Is `Commodity` a column? It appears there is no index

Comment: @Corralien i updated my code to clear confusion. My concern is how to determine how many consecutive rows to combine. if each iteration only needed to combine 2 rows together it would work as i need. The issue arises when I have to combine more than 2 rows since the step value is 2 for each iteration.

Comment: @Corralien indexes are just values 0,1,2, etc

Comment: *My concern is how to determine how many consecutive rows to combine*: you can detect non empty string then use cumsum to create virtual groups. You should look at my answer IIUC.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the date is not always the same please to check the format, please?

Comment: @Corralien i updated the sample data for you

Comment: I'm sorry I expressed myself incorrectly. I wanted an example with 2 different dates for the same ID. (Don't forget to update the expected output)

Comment: @Corralien I dont think i understand your question. Each ID is unique

Comment: Do you mean for an ID, you always have a unique date?

Comment: No, IDs will not be repeated but dates can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC your code, it looks like you don't have a `MultIndex` but simple rows with empty values and you want to group your rows by `ID` and `Date` columns

```
aggfuncs = {k: 'first' for k in df.columns} | {'Stock': list}
g = (df['ID'].str.strip().ne('') | df['Date'].str.strip().ne('')).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(aggfuncs)

# For older versions of python
# aggfuncs = {k: 'first' for k in df.columns}
# aggfuncs.update({'Stock': list})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    ID    Date                      Stock Quantity Price
0  aaa  1Dec23            [Google, Apple]       10  1000
1  bbb  1Dec23            [Google, Apple]       10  1000
2  ccc  1Dec23            [Google, Apple]       10  1000
3  ddd  1Dec23  [Facebook, Google, Apple]       10  1000
4  eee  1Dec23            [Google, Apple]       10  1000
```

Input data:

```
data = [{'ID': 'aaa', 'Date': '1Dec23', 'Stock': 'Google', 'Quantity': '10', 'Price': '1000'},
        {'ID': '', 'Date': '', 'Stock': 'Apple', 'Quantity': '', 'Price': ''},
        {'ID': 'bbb', 'Date': '1Dec23', 'Stock': 'Google', 'Quantity': '10', 'Price': '1000'},
        {'ID': '', 'Date': '', 'Stock': 'Apple', 'Quantity': '', 'Price': ''},
        {'ID': 'ccc', 'Date': '1Dec23', 'Stock': 'Google', 'Quantity': '10', 'Price': '1000'},
        {'ID': '', 'Date': '', 'Stock': 'Apple', 'Quantity': '', 'Price': ''},
        {'ID': 'ddd', 'Date': '1Dec23', 'Stock': 'Facebook', 'Quantity': '10', 'Price': '1000'},
        {'ID': '', 'Date': '', 'Stock': 'Google', 'Quantity': '', 'Price': ''},
        {'ID': '', 'Date': '', 'Stock': 'Apple', 'Quantity': '', 'Price': ''},
        {'ID': 'eee', 'Date': '1Dec23', 'Stock': 'Google', 'Quantity': '10', 'Price': '1000'},
        {'ID': '', 'Date': '', 'Stock': 'Apple', 'Quantity': '', 'Price': ''}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the sample data that you provided; you can use *[`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)* function which is used to read the data from the string, specifying the column widths and names.

```py
data_string = '''
Your data
'''
# Read the data from the string using pandas.read_fwf (fixed-width formatted lines)
data = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(data_string), header=None, widths=[7, 10, 13, 13, 13], names=['ID', 'Date', 'Stock', 'Quantity', 'Price'])

# Fill missing values in 'ID', 'Date', 'Quantity', and 'Price' columns
data[['ID', 'Date', 'Quantity', 'Price']] = data[['ID', 'Date', 'Quantity', 'Price']].fillna(method='ffill')

# Group by 'ID' and aggregate the 'Stock' values into lists
grouped_data = data.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Quantity', 'Price'])['Stock'].apply(list).reset_index()

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(grouped_data)
```

Outputs:

```
    ID    Date  Quantity   Price                      Stock
0  aaa  1Dec23      10.0  1000.0            [Google, Apple]
1  bbb  1Dec23      10.0  1000.0            [Google, Apple]
2  ccc  1Dec23      10.0  1000.0            [Google, Apple]
3  ddd  1Dec23      10.0  1000.0  [Facebook, Google, Apple]
4  eee  1Dec23      10.0  1000.0            [Google, Apple]
```

*[Demo here](https://trinket.io/python3/0b8f65856a)*

---

If you want to read the data from CSV, you can use the [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) function.

```py
# Read the CSV data
data = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv_data.csv')
# Other steps will remain the same as above.
```

*[Demo here](https://trinket.io/python3/9a1baa8069)*

Comment: this did not work for my case

Answer (score 0):

First let's create a sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'ddd', 'ddd', 'ddd'],
                     'Date': ['1Dec23', '1Dec23', '1Dec23', '1Dec23', '1Dec23'],
                     'Stock': ['Google', 'Apple', 'Facebook', 'Google', 'Apple'],
                     'Quantity': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                    'Price': [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000] })
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'Date', 'Stock'])
df = df.reset_index()
df

    ID    Date     Stock  Quantity  Price
0  aaa  1Dec23    Google        10   1000
1  aaa  1Dec23     Apple        10   1000
2  ddd  1Dec23  Facebook        10   1000
3  ddd  1Dec23    Google        10   1000
4  ddd  1Dec23     Apple        10   1000
```

Then we'll do what you are looking for:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Stock'].apply(list).reset_index(name='stock')
df.drop(columns=['Stock'], inplace=True)
df = df.merge(right=df2, on=['ID','Date'], how='right')
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID', 'Date'], inplace=True)
df

    ID    Date  Quantity  Price                      stock
0  aaa  1Dec23        10   1000            [Google, Apple]
2  ddd  1Dec23        10   1000  [Facebook, Google, Apple]
```

Comment: this also did not work for my case. My approach works to format the data. My issue is figuring out how to make the solution work for more than 2 consecutive rows

Comment: Then post a reproducible example of your data. Loops in Pandas are in most cases should be avoided

Comment: that is a reproducible example of my data